# Sharepoint 2010 COM - How to approve tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

We have an Approval workflow in Sharepoint 2010, when users upload a document, they can start this Approval workflow, and specify several people to approve/reject. The document is in `In Process` at the beginning, and moves to `Released` after everyone approved.

Now I want to approve/reject task from ASP.NET web page in C#, it includes:

1. Get all pending tasks by specified people, i.e. if Tom sign in, it can display all tasks which are pending by him, just like when he opens Sharepoint in browser.
2. How to Approve/Reject one task in C#?

I am a new one to Sharepoint Client Object Model, appreciate if someone can give me sample codes to reference, thanks.

Updated:

Here is the code I use, assign credentials to context, but nothing returned in object items, I cannot get task items list.

[Code][1]

Here is the picture for all open items, I do not have tasks assigned, but I can see all in-progress items.

[Open items to be approved picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwsVr.jpg)

New codes still does not work,looks like nothing returned for the method context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");

[Quick watch on object item][1]

Can you please show me how to check list name? I tried to change to WBXmlList, it returned values but cannot read, also does not have key 'AssignedTo'

[WBXmlList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwsVr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario you need, a proper CAML query and task approving code.

**Getting not completed tasks for user:**

```
string url = "http://sharepointsite/";
var context = new ClientContext(url);
var query = @"
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Completed' />
                    <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='True'/>
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>
                        <UserID/>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>";
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = query };
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Approving/Rejecting task:**

```
string outcome = "Approved"; // "Rejected"
var task = GetTask(id); // to implement
task["Completed"] = true;
task["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
task["Status"] = "Completed";
task["WorkflowOutcome"] = outcome;
task["FormData"] = outcome;
```

**Getting all tasks:**

```
string url = "http://sharepointsite/";
var context = new ClientContext(url);    
var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery();
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your codes, I ran it but nothing returned in object "items", I can see several documents are pending to approve in Sharepoint site.

Can you please advise again?

Thanks.

Comment: update your answer with your code so we can work on that - u need to replace my url with yours internal, - like this from your image

Comment: Upload my codes screenshot into my question now, I replaced actual URL already.

Comment: do you have any tasks avaiable for you in Tasks list? check your tasks list from web browser.

Comment: Here is the picture for all open items, I do not have tasks assigned, but I can see all in-progress items. I have full permission of this site, I want to retrieve all tasks with Name, AssignedTo, ID....

Comment: Still does not work, looks like methond context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks"); does not return correct information, so CamlQuery does not work

Comment: do i have to guess or could you check it and try the proper list name?

Comment: Can you please show me how to check list name? I tried to change to WBXmlList, it returned values but cannot read, also does not have key 'AssignedTo'

Comment: use `site contents`